# How do I make a responsive 3 column website?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a 3 column website. Left and right columns are small 240px divs attached to the sides. The middle div is a stretchable area where all the elements inside stretch according to the size of the browser.

So far I have it set up like this :

```
body, html {
height:100%;
} 

body {
margin:0;
}

 .container {
  background:orange;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

.left {
  width:240px;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;

 }

.middle {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:orange;
  }

.right {
  width:240px;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  }
```

And:

```
 <div class="container">

  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle">

     // all the content

  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>

  </div><!--container-->
```

**How do I make the content in the middle column stay in between the left and right columns?** I was thinking to use margin-left and margin-right but I feel it is not a good way of doing it.

Live:

http://codepen.io/daydreamer/pen/0479cc8de929cedc2ac519280a3044aa

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @moettinger I am trying to support all modern browsers in tablets and desktops

Comment: Margins on the middle are in fact a pretty good way with good browser support.  I think I would choose that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supporting modern browsers, I would try using flexbox:

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  
}
.container div {
  flex-grow: 1; 
  height: 50px;
}
.side {
  max-width: 240px;
  min-width: 240px;
  background: red;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="middle">
     // all the content
  </div>
  <div class="side"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vNf9u/)

[Flexbox resource](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Should you use `display: flex` on the `body` for layout? I'm not sure if flex operates similarly to `REM` in that it needs to be set at the `html` level.

Comment: Lindsay, probably not advisable. The column divs would need to be the only direct children within the body which is unlikely. Safer to have an actual div act as the flex container.

Comment: thanks! It sounds like the flex display needs to be used in a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use margin-left, but margin-right would be useful. I would use float: left and get rid of position: absolute on the left sidebar, and use margin-right: 240px and get rid of width: 100% on the middle div.

CSS:

```
.left {
  width:240px;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  float:left;
}

.middle {
  height:100%;
  background:orange;
  margin-right: 240px;
}

.right {
  width:240px;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter [Bootstrap to do n-column design](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) and it will save you a lot of work.  Right click on inspect the HTML code on the example page I provided and you'll see that all you need to do is set classes to a few div's and it works when you include the bootstrap JS/CSS files.